# Modify large XML file with XSLT and PHP and return to user

Tags: php, xml, gpx

I am seeking some advice on the best method to modify an xml file (Garmin TCX file) uploaded to the server then return the modified version to the user without the browser timing out. I need to parse the uploaded file and add some extra elements. For example I need each of these Trackpoint tags:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<TrainingCenterDatabase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2">
  <Activities>
    <Activity Sport="Biking">
      <Id>2018-01-08T18:15:32Z</Id>
      <Lap StartTime="2017-12-16T12:43:09Z">
        <TotalTimeSeconds>5023.91015625</TotalTimeSeconds>
        <DistanceMeters>39999.578125</DistanceMeters>
        <MaximumSpeed>15</MaximumSpeed>
        <Calories>0</Calories>
        <Intensity>Active</Intensity>
        <Cadence>75</Cadence>
        <TriggerMethod>Manual</TriggerMethod>
        <Track>
          <Trackpoint>
            <Time>2017-12-16T12:43:10Z</Time>
            <DistanceMeters>0</DistanceMeters>
            <Cadence>1</Cadence>
            <Extensions>
              <TPX xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2">
                <Speed>0</Speed>
                <Watts>1</Watts>
                <Slope>-1.49</Slope>
              </TPX>
            </Extensions>
          </Trackpoint>
          .....
```

to become:

```
<Trackpoint>
    <Time>2017-12-16T12:43:11Z</Time>
    <DistanceMeters>0</DistanceMeters>
    <Cadence>1</Cadence>
    <Extensions>
        <TPX xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2">
            <Speed>0</Speed>
            <Watts>1</Watts>
            <Slope>-1.49</Slope>
        </TPX>
    </Extensions>
    <AltitudeMeters>106.6</AltitudeMeters>
    <Position>
        <LatitudeDegrees>55.02935</LatitudeDegrees>
        <LongitudeDegrees>-8.140617</LongitudeDegrees>
    </Position>
</Trackpoint>
```

I have the position data and the distance already loaded into an array - already converted from a GPX file. For each trackpoint I search the array for the distance and then append the relevant position data to the trackpoint tag.
The files I'm dealing with could be 5MB-20MB so am not sure what the best way to do this is. 
I understand the DOM parser would be the easiest but also the most memory intensive and slowest. 
I was thinking off using XMLREADER to parse the file and then use XMLWRITER to write all of the trackpoint element + position data to another file.
I do not have access to the server so can only test on local machine.
Any advice is greatly appreciated.
James.

**Update1**
I have a multi-dimensional array loaded from a csv file containing distance, lat, lon, and elevation data. I read the distance from the trackpoint tag and use it as the key for array(key=distance) then return the associated lat and lon data. I then create position, latitude, and longitude elements + text nodes and append to trackpoint tag.

**Update2**
Used Parfait's suggestion - use xsl to add the extra elements. Ran into issues with the default namespace. I could not select any Trackpoint elements. Fixed this using:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
xmlns:e="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2">

 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <!-- Identity Transform -->
 <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity-copy">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy> 
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="e:TrainingCenterDatabase/e:Activities/e:Activity/e:Lap/e:Track/e:Trackpoint">
  <xsl:copy>   
  <xsl:copy-of select="*"/> 
    <AltitudeMeters xmlns = "http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2">xxxx</AltitudeMeters>
    <Position xmlns = "http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2">
    <LatitudeDegrees xmlns = "http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2">laaa</LatitudeDegrees>
    <LongitudeDegrees xmlns = "http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2">looo</LongitudeDegrees>
    </Position>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: you can use the simpleXml php extension which allows you to transform an xml to an array, then add what you want and then turn it back as xml. Probably the easiest way, you may have performances issues with very large xml though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files and at those specified file sizes should be fast rendering. PHP can run XSLT 1.0 with its [php-xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) class.

And since you are iterating through a CSV files to conditional set XSLT values, consider passing values from PHP as parameters into designated placeholders on matching *Distance*.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:doc="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2"              
                exclude-result-prefixes="doc">  
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <!-- Initializing Parameters -->
   <xsl:param name="DistanceParam"/>
   <xsl:param name="AltParam"/>
   <xsl:param name="LatParam"/>
   <xsl:param name="LngParam"/>

    <!-- Copy elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

   <!-- Walk Down Tree Levels -->
   <xsl:template match="doc:TrainingCenterDatabase|doc:Activities|doc:Activity">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc:Id"/>
    <xsl:template match="doc:Lap">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:Track"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Extract Specific TrackPoint -->    
    <xsl:template match="doc:Track">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:Trackpoint[doc:DistanceMeters = $DistanceParam]"/>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="doc:Trackpoint">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">        
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/> 
         <AltitudeMeters><xsl:value-of select="$AltParam"/></AltitudeMeters>
         <Position>
            <LatitudeDegrees><xsl:value-of select="$LatParam"/></LatitudeDegrees>
            <LongitudeDegrees><xsl:value-of select="$LngParam"/></LongitudeDegrees>
         </Position> 
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP**

```
// LOAD XML
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->load('Input.xml');

// LOAD XSLT 
$xsl = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');   
$xsl->load('XSLT_Script.xml');

// INITIALIZE NEW DOM TREE
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('Data'));

// INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

// ITERATE THROUGH CSV ARRAY
foreach($csvdata as $row){

    // BIND LOOP VALUES TO XSLT PARAMETERS
    $proc->setParameter('', 'DistanceParam', $row[0]);
    $proc->setParameter('', 'AltParam', $row[1]);
    $proc->setParameter('', 'LatParam', $row[2]);
    $proc->setParameter('', 'LngParam', $row[3]);

    // TRANSFORM SOURCE
    $newXML = $proc->transformToDoc($xml);

    // IMPORT OUTPUT
    $dom->importNode($newXML->Track->Trackpoint, TRUE);
}

// SAVE NEW DOM TREE TO FILE
file_put_contents('Output.xml', $dom->saveXML());
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.